# Get current place name (in nsstring ) from the coordinates

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, ipad, coordinates

I have coordinates of the current location but how to convert those coordinates into the place name?I don't want to show map view. Since MKReverseGeocoder is deprecated in iOS 5, is there any other method to achieve this.
Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 0):

You can access the Google Places Api

http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q=yourSearchName&output=xml

This will give details about that searchname provided. You can parse the xml and get latitude and longitude from that details and can pin annotate those locations.

The output can be in json and csv also.

Some code that can help

```
 NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q=%@&output=csv",coordinate];   //coordinate=-30.347744,71.3737373
 NSString *locationString = [NSString  stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
 NSArray *listItems = [locationString componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
```

Refer Google APi [Here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/webservices/)

Comment: Thanks but is there any way without using xml or json and csv? using only iOS api.

Comment: I think instead of MKReverseGeocoder Apple moved to CLGeocoder.  try using this. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLGeocoder_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/CLGeocoder

Comment: Is there any sample code for that? I have seen CLGeocoder but i dint figure it out how to implement it and id i am not wrong we have to use map for that.

Comment: Sample code for CLGeocoder can be found in the Location Awareness Programming Guide.

Comment: Can you post some sample code ? i am not able to figure out the code in location awareness programming guide.

Comment: Did you read the guide? It gives an exact example. Any code I post here would be exactly the same.